# SSO in multi-tenant application: what about malicious admins?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid, multi-tenant

We have a multi-tenant web application and are busy implementing SSO (OpenID with Azure) and are considering a possible security issue.

In our application, it is possible that a user has access to multiple tenants. Regular authentication is done centrally, the system then checks which tenants you have access to, if it's more than one you get to choose which tenant you want to access. We are considering functionality where, once you are logged in, you can switch between tenants without having to log in again.

The (theoretical) issue is this:

1. Tenant A has a user Bob that has regular access to their data
2. Malicious Tenant B sets up SSO, where they can fully control user management
3. Malicious Tenant B knows Bob's email address, and add him to their SSO directory, setting a password of their choice
4. Malicious Tenant B logs in on our system as Bob, and switches to Tenant A

Is this a common threat? Do known identity providers (Microsoft, Facebook, Google) always force the user to set a password themselves, or require email verification? Or is our situation unique in that usually multi-tenant applications don't allow users to switch tenants, without re-authenticating?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is about trust and scope. Information provided by an Identity Provider (IDP) should only be trusted in a constricted scoped. So if Tenant A has a SSO setup, the information (claims) provided by their IDP should only be valid for their tenant.

So the e-mail address provided by some IDP can be only valid for that IDP. You shouldn't assume the e-mail address provided by some IDP to be validated in any capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to have the user sent a welcome email with the temporary password. Once the user logs in from the ok link, they change the password of their choice and then complete the setup. This process also involves setting up the MFA authenticator or SMS based token authentication.

In the case where MFA is enabled, unless the malicious user has access to both the password and the MFA device, the user account stands secured.

Comment: What is unclear to me is whether all the big SSO providers (Microsoft, Google, Facebook) always force the use of such a temporary password. Because if a malicious admin can set their SSO up so that it doesn't, the attack vector will work.


I've been trying to find out more about this, and the fact that this article exists https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr describing the **option** of self-service password reset for Azure, doesn't comfort me.